# jQuery - Context menu - unbind

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu, bind, unbind

I use a plugin for jQuery - ContextMenu. - http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/09/jquery-context-menu-plugin/

I want to do on the button - click event - an event contextMenu cancel.

I tried this code: (*This does not work correctly.*)

**JS**

```
$("#btnUnbind").click(function () {
    $('.icon').unbind('contextMenu');
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="myMenu" class="contextMenu">            
    <li class="delete"><a href="#delete">Delete</a></li>            
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
  $(".icon").contextMenu(
                    { 
                        menu: 'myMenu' 
                    }, 
                    function(action, el, pos) 
                    { 
                        contextMenuWork(action, el, pos); 
                    });

     function contextMenuWork(action, el, pos) {
                switch (action) {
                    case "delete":
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your 1st and 2nd javascript you select .icon, this doesn't exist in your HTML example.

Also in the 2nd javascript you forgot to put .icon between quotes:

```
$(.icon)
```

should be:

```
$('.icon')
```

Also to disable the context menu use the following on the selected jquery object:

```
.disableContextMenu();
```

So in your case instead of using unbind use:

```
$('.icon').disableContextMenu();
```

Comment: Ah ok, well to disable your contextMenu see my edited answer.